# How to write code that runs in the "background" indefinitely

Tags: javascript, mongodb, frontend, backend

I have access to an API, with a minimal request limit, and I'm planning to display some data from this API unto my web app. However I don't want users having to initiate requests to this endpoint since that will make me reach the daily cap quicker, and may even ban my account.

My solution is to write some js code, that sends requests to the api in intervals, and updates a mongodb cluster with the returned data, thus instead of users directly accessing the api endpoint, they access data from their session storage that is updated in intervals with data from the mongodb cluster.

Issue is, I have no idea what an implementation of this looks like. The code must run independently of the client, and must continue to run whether the webpage is currently been visited or not. Any ideas are welcomed.

Comment: Just use a Javascript timer event. You can find it in the Javascript documentation. (HINT: `setTimeout` and `setInterval`).

Comment: You may use to the window.setInterval function to do so.

Comment: This sounds a lot like a cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needs to run on server-side, due to the limit of requests and security concerns regarding API secrets.

Since this needs to be executed on the server and you have mentioned Javascript, I will assume npm. You are looking for [heartbeat events](https://www.npmjs.com/package/heartbeats), or [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron), or something similar. Your server will be polling the API and your clients will need to be repeatedly notified of changes, either by polling from the client-side to download the latest information your server is aware of, or, even create some websocket channels, or push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

This will run for every five seconds

```
setInterval(function(){ /*your logic here */ }, 5000);
```

Comment: the code must be server side so only 1 instance of it should be running at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to set up a separate app that runs on a set interval. Personally, I accomplish this by creating a small console app that I then configure a system to run via a cron job.

Without knowing what type of a backend you have available, it's difficult to provide a code answer, however all you have to do is create something that can be executed. Within that code, you simply make the call to the external API and then store the results within your own database. Once you have that code written, you can setup a timer event/cron job (depending on your system) and set it to run at whatever interval you need.